# How to use if condition for location

Tags: javascript, java, android, api

My application api url is
example.com/api in variables.java file

```
public static final string main_domain ="example.com/api";
```

I want to use different url for different country (location based)
Then how to set if condition like

```
if(location=india){    public static final string main_domain ="example1.com/api";}
 if(location=us){    public static final string main_domain ="example.com/api";}
```

Comment: if (x == 0) {} else if (x < 0) {} else {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial example above consists of two countries: india and us.  It is likely that you want to include more countries based on the context of the example.  Using switch is better.  Try this:

```
String mainDomain;

// assuming the location variable is a String
switch (location) {
 
    case "india":
        mainDomain = "example1.com/api";
        break;
    
    case "us":
        mainDomain = "example.com/api";
        break;

    // more cases here

    default:
        mainDomain = "example.com/api";
}

// mainDomain is available as a non-null String here
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct comparisson sign is (==).

```js
if(location == us){ //code }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple api urls (five or more), I suggest using a map.

First you will have to import it like this:

`import java.util.HashMap; // import the HashMap class`

Then create it like this:

`HashMap<String, String> apiUrl = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Then add key value pair like this:

`apiUrl.put('india', 'https://example1.com/api');`

`apiUrl.put('us', 'https://example.com/api');`
`//and so on`

Then you can use it directly like this:

`public static final String main_domain = apiUrl.get(location);` //note that it is `String`, not `string`.

You can use get() method of HashMap to access a particular key. If you already know the key (if you want to refer to it directly), you can use it like

`String url = apiUrl.get('us');`

Otherwise, if you have a variable which contains the country name, you can use the variable like

`String url = apiUrl.get(location);`

You might be getting location value from the user as input or it might be stored in database, from where you fetch it and use.

Comment: I am beginner please provide detailed information and how to get keys from HashMap  and location

Comment: You can use get() method of HashMap to access a particular key. If you already know the key (if you want to refer to it statically), you can use it like

`String url = apiUrl.get('us');`....

Otherwise, if you have a variable which contains the country name, you can use the variable like

`String url = apiUrl.get(location);`....

You might be getting location from the user as input or it might be stored in database, from where you fetch it and use.